# Merge Two Folders To Act As One (Software Raid 0?)

Tags: windows, raid

Using Windows 7, I'm trying to setup what I've come to call a "Software Raid of Folders", not completely sure it's the right term, but I'm sure anyone who knows the true term will understand what I'm getting at.

I have two folders, on two seperate harddrive, I would like to "merge" these folders while keeping them on seperate harddrive so they act as one folder. Example:

**Music** and **Videos** are to be merged together to a new folder called **"Merged"**

**Music** runs off of ***Harddrive 1***

**Videos** runs off of ***Harddrive 2***

Anything new saved inside **Merged** is saved within **Videos** that runs off of ***Harddrive 2***

Now you see how I came up with the term "Software Raid", it's like an average RAID 0 setup, but instead I want to do it with just two specific folders on two different drives within Windows. Any help on this is apprecieated!

Comment: Why will new things be saved on Harddrive 2 as opposed to Harddrive 1? I think software raid is a bad analogy here.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like 7's in-built "Libraries".  Why not just use those?

Comment: Essentially it's for a Server with a lot of data stored on it, another harddrive was added but they can't reconfigured their hardware RAID. So I'm looking for a software alternative as the software they are using completely works out of one folder. And Libraries? I wasn't aware they were customizable. How would you go about it?

Comment: why can't they reconfigure hardware RAID? Seems like a pretty typical operation.

Comment: As far as I knew, it would require a full reinstallation of the server wouldn't it?

Comment: Should need a reinstall, but it would depend on the array controller.

Comment: Shouldn't need an install I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [junctions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28v=ws.10%29.aspx),

You could have a folder, let's call it Merged
Within that you have two subfolders Videos and Music and each of these sub folders contents reisde on different hdd.

Open a command prompt to the Merged directory and type the following, replacing  with the name of the folder, e.g. Music and  with the destination, e.g. D:\Music

```
mklink /j <junction_point_name> <target>
```

Comment: Hang on, this creates two seperate folders, right? Instead of merging two?

Comment: that's correct. see my comment on your question - how should it know which filesystem to save files to?

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using spanned volumes then if the data must not be in subfolders. However you'll need to make a backup of all the data from the existing volumes as it's a destructive process.

"[Spanned volumes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772180.aspx) are a dynamic volume consisting of disk space on more than one physical disk."

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see this working from my experience is using unallocated space of the same size on each of the additional HDD to create a Software raid using Windows disk manager, then if you want that to be a folder, then map it as a Folder when formatting it. I might be able to make a video of that once my Raid 5 finishes rebuilding.

Comment: Howerever you could just symlink the music and video folders

Comment: When looking at the edited questions, it does seem that creating a folder with two sym links in it is probably the best way to create your solution. So aland's answer is probably the most correct however there is a couple programs that you can use that would make symlinking easier than command line if you struggle with that sort of thing. The sym links are what let the OS know where the data is actually going, however, it will seem like all the data is on the HDD with the "Merged" folder. Good luck.